# How to get Form/Post Parameter when it posted?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, http-post, httplistener

I am trying to get Form/Post Parameters from the page when my client HTTP post the data. I don't know how to retrieve when client posts data and wait for the data in the page. 
In below example `checkin` and `user` are parameters.

Do I need to write any listener for this? How to read the Form/Post Parameters from in my page?

Answer (score 0):

you can make checkin and user class with all atribute that needed,

```
public class Checkin
{ 

 public int Id{get;set;}  
 public String FirstName{get;set;}
 //another attribute
}

public class User
{
 public int Id{get;set}
 public string Name{get;set}  

}
```

and when you post from page you can write like this

```
var checkin = {id:528,FirstName:John}; 

var user = {id:1,Name:"John};
```

create action in controller like this

```
public actionResult(Checkin checkin,User user){
//body method here
}
```